# I can't access to phpmyadmin on wampserver

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

A question about wamp server. I just installed it on my computer and when I want to use phpmyadmin, I have this message:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I tried to change the password in config.inc but it didn't work.

I tried to reinstall wampserver but nothing worked?

Comment: I tried to reinstall wampserver but nothing worked !!!?!

Answer (score 4):

Change the following database config values in your config.default.php:

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOUR_Password';
```

Comment: I haven't found these lines in wamp/apps/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php

Comment: You can visit this link: http://www.mombu.com/gnu_linux/suse/t-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno-13265791.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you check `config.inc.php`? There must be a row like `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`

`config.inc.php` is in `./wamp/apps/phpmyadmin[yourVersion]`

Answer (score 1):

User: Root

Password: (leave blank)

Click Go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to: `config.default.php`
I think that it is located in `C:\wamp\phpmyadmin\config.default.php`

- also check `config.inc.php`

Find: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] =`

If it is `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';`

Change it to: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';`

**ALSO CHECK OTHER CONFIGS THERE!**

Comment: Writing that many exclamation points and question marks will not do you any good... It is considered rude. That is not what is expected from somebody who asks a question that personally don't know how to answer.

Answer (score 0):

since 'using password: NO', You don'r need to write a password. just click 'go'